# React page many requests per server

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[image: 1]

When i go to the page, the front sends 4 requests to the server.
Response is the same.
I have 4 useEffect, two of them spend a 2 request, but from where two more requests?
This is normal or not?

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    loadData({ aspect, query })

    return () => {
      timer.current && clearTimeout(timer.current)
      resetBrandsList()
    }
  }, [])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (!isLoading && aspect !== prevAspect) {
      resetBrandsList()
      setIsLoading(true)
      loadData({ aspect, query: "" }).then(recoverScrollPos)
    }
  }, [aspect, isLoading])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    resetBrandsList()
    setIsLoading(true)
    loadData({ aspect, query, page: brands.page })
  }, [query])

  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (isLoading) {
      recoverScrollPos()
    }
  }, [isLoading])
```

Comment: When isLoading state changes, two use useEffect are triggered

Comment: Check the state variable changes.

Answer (score 0):

```
React.useEffect(() => {
 if (isLoading) {
   recoverScrollPos()
 }
}, [isLoading])
```

No need of above. You can merge this code to below

```
React.useEffect(() => {
 if (!isLoading && aspect !== prevAspect) {
  resetBrandsList()
  setIsLoading(true)
  loadData({ aspect, query: "" }).then(recoverScrollPos)
 }

  if (isLoading) {
   recoverScrollPos()
 }
}, [aspect, isLoading])
```